# Affine to linear like conversion of a concave function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Is the following true:

$$\log \left( \frac{1}{f(x)+K}\right)\mathrm{is\;concave}\Longleftrightarrow \log \left( \frac{1}{f(x)}\right)\mathrm{is\;concave},$$
where $K\in\mathbb{R} $ and  $f(x),f(x)+K>0$?$

Comment: Why would you expect this to be true? Did you try differentiating twice (assuming $f$ is twice differentiable)?

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen: According to http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf , 3.2.2 if $g(x) = f(Ax + b)$ and $f(x)$ is concave then so is $g(x)$. I understand that my example is not the same, but there is hint of similarity.

I was thinking, perhaps, $g(f(x))\;\mathrm{is\;concave}\Longleftrightarrow g(A f(x)+b)\;\mathrm{is\;concave}$

Comment: But that similarity is way too weak. Replacing $x$ by $Ax+b$ will just stretch the graph in the horizontal direction (by a factor $A$) and translate it horizontally (an amount $b$), and it should be “visually obvious” that this operation preserves concavity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider a smooth function $f$ and let $g(x)=\log(1/f(x))=-\log(f(x))$.
Differentiate to get $g'(x)=-f'(x)/f(x)$, and repeat to get $$g''(x)=\frac{\bigl(f'(x)\bigr)^2-f(x)f''(x)}{\bigl(f(x)\bigr)^2}$$
so $g$ is (strictly) concave iff $$\bigl(f'(x)\bigr)^2<f(x)f''(x).$$
If you were to replace $f(x)$ by $f(x)+K$ this inequality becomes instead
$$\bigl(f'(x)\bigr)^2<\bigl(f(x)+K\bigr)f''(x),$$
and clearly the two inequalities are not equivalent.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your help. Can I divert you to [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/906326/78492). It's another more recent and fairly related question that I've asked.